# Alternative to BufferedStream in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I'm targeting an IoT core device that I'm hoping to run a UWP application on. The project is primarily to process a motion JPEG stream, but in setting up that stream I've found that System.IO doesn't seem to contain a definition for 'BufferedStream'.

I wanted to wrap a 'BinaryReader' around a 'BufferedStream', because I need to both minimise the number of IO reads on the transport, as well as tell the 'BinaryReader' to read and return a given number of bytes. Reading directly doesn't always return all the bytes, which is problematic when I'm subsequently processing the image looking for certain elements.

```
public class MultiPartStream
{
    public MultiPartStream(Stream multipartStream)
    {
        _reader = new BinaryReader(new BufferedStream(multipartStream));
    }
```

What's my alternative here? There's an [old thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1793) purporting to have added support for 'BufferedStream' to .NET core, so where is it?

Comment: How do you get the JPEG stream?

Comment: The IP camera I'm working with outputs a JPEG stream.